# Getting rid of NA group in legend of plot?

Tags: legend, non-linear-regression, nlme

I wanted to force my nlme regression line through the origin so I added a (0,0) data point to my data sheet. I didn't give it a site and this is resulting in a NA group in the legend of the graph. It achieved in forcing the line through the origin but I want to get rid of that NA group but don't know how to...
This is my first time using this website so lmk if I am leaving important info out.
Thank you in advance!

[NA in the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqPCU.png)

```
ggplot(dfyielal,aes(x=HP1,y=AY1))+
  geom_point(aes(shape = Site), size = 4, alpha = 0.5)+
  stat_function(fun=fun.56YieldSite,size=1.2, color = "black")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 18)+
  labs(y=expression("Black Bean Yield (kg"~ha^-1*')'),
       x=expression("Black Bean Density (plants"~ha^-1*')'))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),labels = scales::comma,limits=c(0,3500)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma, 
                     breaks=c(0,185300,370700,556000,741300,926600))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Accent")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1),
        legend.position="bottom")
```